# Is it time for a new battery?

Tags: iphone, battery

I have an iPhone SE, for just over a year. My battery health which I find in settings is decreasing quite rapidly.

Right now it is at 94%:

[image]

Recently it has been going down around 1% a month.

After December 31st, the battery replacement will be more expensive. When should a battery be replaced and do you think it is time to replace mine? Are my vlaues normal?

Comment: Start by checking the charge holding capacity and the cycle count using [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) app.

Comment: your values are all normal, so what is the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need and should not get a new battery. 94% after a year is pretty good. Apple’s recommendation is a replacement if the battery gets below 80% of maximum capacity. The cost increase after the 31st isn’t so much that it’s worth replacing so early.

For context, my iPhone 6s, which I received the day it was released, is at 75% maximum capacity after pretty heavy usage for over 3 years, so you don’t have anything to worry about for a while. (I’m hopefully going to get the battery before the end of the year.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to replace the battery  for at least 3 years. Even after solid usage. iOS 12 is really good on the battery. Don't let the battery hit 20% or less all the time before you push some juice into it.

- Apple products have really long life which is good as it lasts years.
- If you need a second opinion, visit an Apple store, just hear what they say but listen to yourself before you decide and this is only after you hit 80% of max capacity.

Replace it only when you think that your phone is pushing too hard for normal tasks and you run out of battery before evening or so.