# My iPhone SE only boots on quick charge

Tags: iphone, startup, battery, charging

When I try to boot it it shows the Apple logo for a second and then gives up, same with Recovery mode.

When I put it on quick charge it boots up and works but when I unplug it, it slows down and then shuts off.

I've managed to do a quick change from quick charge to the laptop USB port while it was in Recovery mode and am currently reinstalling the software.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking us if you should seek hardware repair? What specifically does “any ideas” mean - we don’t really know what you want to have answered or what knowledge you could use if you don’t ask a direct question.

Answer (score 3):

**The battery is dead and needs to be replaced.**

If you can only power on and use your phone while it's plugged in, then the battery can no longer hold a charge.  It needs to be replaced.

- [Fully charged MacBook Air turns off when power cord removed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/124839/119271)
- [iPhone turning off on low battery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/345930/119271)

"Quick charging" has to do with the current that the *charger* supplies.  It's not a mode you can select.  Laptops don't have the ability to quick charge as a typical USB port only provides 5V at 500mA max.  You need at least 2.4A to quick charge (12W).

You can try doing a [hard reset of the phone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios), but if the problem persists, it's definitely a failing/failed battery and it will need to be replaced.